# Compile time checks for interface proxy

Tags: c#, class, interface, behavior

**A bit of context**

I have a class that takes in a "Handler", like this:

```
interface IHandler
{
    void DoSomething(MyType type, string s);
}

public class MyType
{
    private IHandler handler;

    public MyType(IHandler handler = null)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string s)
    {
        handler?.DoSomething(this, s);
    }
}
```

**The issue**

I want to make ensure that all the methods from `IHandler` are implemented in `MyType`, without the first parameter `MyType type`, which is to be filled in the handler call with `this`.

**My question**

Is there a pattern that allows such a thing? I thought of inheriting from `IHandler` in `MyType`, but that requires the caller to specify the type in the call, which defeats the purpose. I could also just make sure that they all get called by hand, but the interface is going to become quite huge, and might have a couple of parent interfaces. This is my last resort. I don't really mind changing the code if it needs to.

**My goal with this**

I want to be able to add behaviours in the `MyType` class while allowing the handler to be null (not adding behaviours). I chose this sort of pattern, but I'm only planning the code, so changing anything that would give me this set of features would be great.

Comment: What if you changed it to `DoSomething(string s)` then when you implement it in `MyType` you don't need to pass an instance of `MyType` since it is a `MyType`?

Comment: @juharr Because `IHandler` might handle multiple types of `MyType`, and I need to know which one it is in the `IHandler` methods! :)

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off with [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx0).  I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Why should `MyType` itself implements method of interface it doesn't inherit? What if you have to add `IAnotherHandler` with another set of methods?

`MyType` looks like a wrapper to call `IHandler` methods without specifying `MyType`. If handlers are created by `MyType`, then you can pass `this` as constructor parameter (to keep encapsulation, without it you can simply make a property to assign `this`)

```
public class MyType
{
    public IHandler Handler { get; }

    public MyType() { }

    public MyType(IHandlerFactory factory)
    {
        // create instance via factory
        Handler = factory.CreateHandler(this);
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to call handler method via property:

```
var test = new MyType(new ConcreteFactory()); // with handler
// var test = new MyType(); // without handler
test.Handler?.DoSomething("test"); // you will have to check for `null` always
```

It should be easy to add more methods to handler or more handlers to `MyType` without modifying much of code.

---

I would use base class for handlers:

```
abstract class Handler
{
   MyType _type;

   public Handler(MyType type)
   {
       Type = type;
   }

    public abstract void DoSomething(string s) { ... }
}

class ConcreteHandler: Handler
{
    public override void DoSomething(string s) { ... }
}

interface IHandlerFactory
{
    Handler CreateHandler(MyType type);
}

class ConcreteFactory: IHandlerFactory
{
    public Handler CreateHandler(MyType type) => new ConcreteHandler(type);
}
```

Comment: I think the point was that the instance of `MyType` would be passed in as the first parameter.

Comment: @juharr, see edit. It solves initial problem (which I answered first) with unnecessary wrapping of `IHandler` methods in `MyType` and removing needs to pass instance of `MyType` for each handler method.